# JUnit Category doesn't work with TestCase?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I found a strange thing and I'm interested to know why it happens. I'm using maven surefire plugin ( 2.12.4 ) with Junit 4.11. When I wanted to use `@Category` annotation in order to disable some tests. the strange thing that it works correctly only with tests that don't extend `TestCase`. For test that don't extend `TestCase` I was able to put the annotation only on the test method to run/disable, but with others it disables all tests in the class.
Example:
Command Line:
`mvn test -Dgroups=!testgroups.DisabledTests` run only test B for the first snippet:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class DataTest {
    @Test
    public void testA(){...} 

    @Test @Category(testgroups.DisabledTests.class)
    public void testB(){...}
}
```

for the second case with class extending `TestCase`, it will run no tests.

```
public class DataTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testA(){...} 

    @Test @Category(testgroups.DisabledTests.class)
    public void testB(){...}
}
```

Why it happens?

Comment: The problem is, that the second class is an extension of TestCase. Since this is JUnit 3 style, the annotation  @Category didn't work. Annotating the class with @RunWith(JUnit4.class) should give you the same result in both cases

Comment: Thanks. I already wrote in the question that the issue is in 'TestCase', but I didn't know why. Do you mean that 'TestCase' is deprecated for JUnit 4?

Comment: JUnit 4 finds test by looking for the `@Test` annotation. You can remove the `extends TestCase` from your test class. Furthermore the name of the test method does no longer have to start with `test`. You're free to choose any method name you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was given in a comment by [deborah-digges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2591330/deborah-digges):

> The problem is that the second class is an extension of TestCase. Since this is JUnit 3 style, the annotation  @Category didn't work. Annotating the class with @RunWith(JUnit4.class) should give you the same result in both cases

and another by [Stefan Birkner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557091/stefan-birkner):

> JUnit 4 finds test by looking for the `@Test` annotation. You can remove the `extends TestCase` from your test class. Furthermore the name of the test method does no longer have to start with `test`. You're free to choose any method name you want.